# nginx: error_page does not work

Tags: nginx, 503-error, custom-errors

I try to set up a maintenance page for my rails app, using this snipplet.

```
error_page 503 /system/maintenance.html;
if (-f $document_root/system/maintenance.html) {
  return 503;
}
```

This works as far as the presence of the maintenance.html causes the webserver to return a 503. But it returns the minimal nginx default error_page, not my maintenance.html. Why?

nginx 1.0.12 on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS

The complete vhost configuration: https://gist.github.com/1948225

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"if" and "return" directives are the part of ngx_rewrite_module. Since you declare such condition at server level you don't live a chance to nginx to handle error_page.

Make your config clear:

```
root /home/igel/www/stage.example.com/current/public;
error_page 503 /system/maintenance.html;

location / {
       if ( -e /system/maintenance.html ) {
              return 503;
       }
}
location = /system/maintenance.html {
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I modified your code a little, though, since the rails app didn't work, if I didn't specify passenger_enabled within the location: https://gist.github.com/1965393